# Strange behavior in Redis + Node.js + Socket.io + Django/Celery setup. Disconnected sockets still receive messages

Tags: django, node.js, redis, socket.io, celery

I'm facing with a strange problem, which I can't solve by myself. I've established a setup where I send JSON-serialized messages through a Django/Celery periodic task. This task communicates through Redis with a node.js server. Node.js handles the communication through socket.io with the webbrowser.

**Django/Celery task**

```
@periodic_task(run_every=crontab()) # every minute
def process_channels():
     r = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)

     for i in xrange(1,21): # 1..20
         data_dict = {}
         data_dict['time'] = time.ctime(time.time())
         data_dict['message'] = os.urandom(10).encode('hex')
         r.publish('channel', json.dumps(data_dict) )
         time.sleep(2)
```

**node.js server**

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer().listen(4000);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var querystring = require('querystring')
var redis = require('socket.io/node_modules/redis');
var sub = redis.createClient();

sub.subscribe('channel');

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    // grab message from Redis and send to client
    sub.on('message', function(channel, message) {
        console.log(message + ' ' + channel + ' ' + socket.id);
        socket.send(message);
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
         console.log('disconnected')
    });
});
```

**index.html**

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
         var socket = io.connect('localhost', {
              port: 4000
         });

         socket.on('connect', function() {
              console.log("connecting");
         });

         socket.on('message', function(message) {
             // deserialize message from DJANGO
             var data = JSON.parse(message);

             //Append message to the bottom of the list
             $('#comments').append('Time: ' + data.time + '<br />');
             $('#comments').append('Message: ' + data.message + '<br /><br />');
          } });
     });
```

Pretty simple. The Task is sending randomly generated messages via Redis to the node server where it is being sent to the Browser. As you can see I'm logging the message and socket.id inside the node server.

Everything works as expected until I do a page reload. When I load the page for the first time the server console prints something like that:

```
{"message": "85105676e21512a33e72", "time": "Fri Oct 18 22:33:10 2013"} channel 94k39P2j9dMv1JEZRW6Q
```

When I make a page reload this appears:

```
disconnected
{"message": "c3e93646d60a5a6727f6", "time": "Fri Oct 18 22:33:18 2013"} channel 94k39P2j9dMv1JEZRW6Q
{"message": "c3e93646d60a5a6727f6", "time": "Fri Oct 18 22:33:18 2013"} channel wJwsRvpgEks7g1AURW6R
```

The same message has been sent two times. Everytime I reload the page the message is sent one more time. Looking at the socket.ids (3rd field) it seems to be that the socket wasn't disconnected properly before reloading and the server is still sending the message through that socket. I don't understand this behavior. The 'disconnect' method was called, so it should be handeled in any way. Can someone help me out?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Shot in the dark, but maybe consider setting 'force new connection' to true on the client?

Answer (score 0):

Try socket.once() instead of socket.on() on the client side.

```
socket.once('message', function() {
   ...
}
```

The problem probably is that every time you reload the page, multiple listeners are attached. I faced a similar issue and '.once()' was the only solution I could find.

If this doesn't help, you could try exploring a similar issue posted here. Hope it helps :)
https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/issues/997